# Rails tutorial - cannot get patch test to work - patch unrecognized method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

Here's some snippets of code - if you need more, just let me know and I will post it.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) # user_params
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

and then the unit test...

```
describe "authorization" do
...
                describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
                    before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
                    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
                end
```

If I run this, I get the message:

> FailureError: before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
>   NoMethodError:
>       undefined method `patch' for # RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x...

If I change patch to post, I get this...

> FailureError: before { post user_path(wrong_user) }
>   ActionController::RoutingError:
>       No route matches [POST] "users/1497"

---

the error for put actually indicates that the test is getting redirected to the sign-in path, but when I test it out in the browser, it redirected to the root path as expected.  I wonder if my session isn't persisting in the test.  I remember let giving me some sort of trouble like this before in previous tests...

Here is the rest of the test code:

```
    describe "for wrong user" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
        before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

        describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
            before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
            it { should_not have_title(full_title('Edit user')) }
        end

        describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
            before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
            specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
        end
    end # end for wrong user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`patch` exists in Rails 4, is you are using Rails 3.2 (that's what mentioned in your question's tags) you need to use `put` instead

Comment: It would seem that my issue is that somehow, my user is not signed in.  When I test in the browser, everything works fine, but when I run the unit test, put actually redirects me to the signin page.  However, I have a previous test that relies on that sign_in method that works...

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you was using rails 3.2, next time please tag your question correctly :) Glad you found the fix anyhow. Cheers

Comment: Well, you WERE correct - put worked, which revealed the REAL error, haha, which is that when submitting a put request to update for the wrong user, I was getting redirected to the wrong page.

Comment: Ah good! :) So my answer is correct, kindly accept it if you don't mind